# using DataColumn's Expression property get concated text from ChildRows

Tags: c#, expression, datacolumn

I have DataSet within two DataTable, MasterTable has PK relation link to DetailTable. I know expression can help to Summary the value of child like

```
dtMaster.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TotalQty", 0, "Sum(child.Qty)"));
```

but I need to concate string, like

```
dtMaster.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("HasErrors", 0, "Concat(child.ErrorText + ';')"));
```

I know column expression not support concat, so for now, I need to detect Table.ColumnChanging event to menually set the master's HasError field value.

can someone guild me a more automatic way doing this?

here is my sample code

```
    internal static void Test()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();

        var dtMaster = ds.Tables.Add("Master");

        var colIDMaster = dtMaster.Columns.Add("ID");

        var dtDetail = ds.Tables.Add("Detail");

        var colIDDetail = dtDetail.Columns.Add("ID");
        dtDetail.Columns.Add("CID");
        dtDetail.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
        dtDetail.Columns.Add("ErrorText", typeof(string), "IIF(Qty is null, 'Qty err', '')");

        ds.Relations.Add("m2d", colIDMaster, colIDDetail, false);

        //I know I can do this
        dtMaster.Columns.Add("TotalQty", typeof(int), "Sum(child.Qty)");
        //here is I am asking solution
        //dtMaster.Columns.Add("ContainErrors", typeof(string), "Concat(child.ErrorText + ';')");

        var newMasterRow = dtMaster.NewRow();
        newMasterRow["ID"] = "A";
        dtMaster.Rows.Add(newMasterRow);

        var newDetailRow = dtDetail.NewRow();
        newDetailRow["ID"] = "A";
        newDetailRow["CID"] = "D1";
        newDetailRow["Qty"] = DBNull.Value;
        dtDetail.Rows.Add(newDetailRow);

        newDetailRow = dtDetail.NewRow();
        newDetailRow["ID"] = "A";
        newDetailRow["CID"] = "D2";
        newDetailRow["Qty"] = 10;
        dtDetail.Rows.Add(newDetailRow);

        //now I can loop and print the  master row with ID and it's ErrorTexts
    }
```

thanks for help

Comment: Please elaborate more this question

Comment: added sample code, and I wish I can see  master's row[0]["ContainErrors"] has text 'Qty Err; ...' <- if more then one child has ErrorText

Answer (score 0):

You need to add column value change event in Detail .

```
   dtDetail.ColumnChanged += dtDetail_ColumnChanged;

    static void dtDetail_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.ColumnName == "Qty")
        {
            int sum = 0;
           // dtMaster.Columns.Add("TotalQty"
            foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["Detail"].Rows)
            {
                if (row["Qty"] != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToString(row["CID"]) != Convert.ToString(e.Row["CID"]))
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(row["Qty"]);
                }
            }

            sum += Convert.ToInt32(e.Row["Qty"]);

            ds.Tables["Master"].Rows[0]["TotalQty"] = sum;

        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for my english, I already done what I want via handle DetailTable's ColumnChanging event. and the importent is I need solution for string cancating, not int sum. which can easily use Sum(child.Qty) in master's expression. thank you for any further suggestion.